# Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error encrypting or decrypting credentials

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, psconfig

i removed server from existing farm from central administratin _admin/FarmServers.aspx Servers in farm page, and after in exsting WFE servers and  when i join the server to existing farm i get below error

> Task configdb has failed with an unknown exception 
>   ----  9  ERR Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error encrypting or decrypting credentials. Either a credential update
>   is currently being performed, or you must update the farm account
>   credentials on this server before you can perform this task.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPEncryptedString.CheckCredentialLock()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPManagedAccount.Deploy(SPApplicationPool
>   applicationPool)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceInstance.Provision()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Join()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask() 
>   Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage

I clered the configuration cache in all servers and run the again updatefarm credential command and after got the below error in event viewer Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance ().

Reason: There was an error encrypting or decrypting credentials. Either a credential update is currently being performed, or you must update the farm account credentials on this server before you can perform this task.

Technical Support Details:
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error encrypting or decrypting credentials. Either a credential update is currently being performed, or you must update the farm account credentials on this server before you can perform this task.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean isAdministrationServiceJob

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above problem do the following:

1. Go to SharePoint Server which host the Central administration
2. Go to run and then open Services.msc
3. Restart these services: 
   *SharePoint 2010 Administration. 
   *SharePoint 2010 Timer.
4. Then go to new server and re-run the configuration wizard again
5. configured successfully.

> Note:You have to Login to the new server by Farm service account who
>   has the following permissions:

1. Domain user account and not domain admin user.
2. This user Belong to the following SQL Roles

   Public 
   Securityadmin 
   Dbcreator
3. Belong to Local administrators group of SharePoint servers

[Source & more information](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2011/10/24/error-in-configuration-wizard-while-trying-to-add-new-sharepoint-server-to-an-existing-farm-scale-out-after-reset-the-farm-passphrase/)

Comment: please check my updated question, now how i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like removal of server did not complete successfully. As per my experience, if you remove a server from central admin, it will not disconnect the server from farm.

> "If a server is no longer available, or if uninstalling SharePoint
>   Server 2016 from Control Panel is not possible, you can remove the
>   SharePoint server from the farm by using the SharePoint Central
>   Administration website."

You should use PSCofnig wizard to remove the server from Farm or use the powershell to disconnect the server from farm or uninstall the SharePoint from control panel.

[Removing a server from a SharePoint farm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/remove-a-server-from-a-farm-in-sharepoint-server-2016)

Comment: please check my updated question and there is some more errors

Comment: I think problem is on 1st step, the way you removed the server from farm.

Comment: now how can i solve this issue , i can not able to join that  sever  again , when i run configuration wizard the same error.